# Getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset Error Message while Setting Email Notifications for Gmail server

Tags: jenkins, smtp, jenkins-plugins, gmail-pop, jenkins-email-ext

I Want to setup Email Notifications in Jenkins Server. Tried with Gmail Server using below Settings.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InZCH.png)

Here is the Error Message I am getting:-
Failed to send out e-mail

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)

at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
```

Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)

at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)

at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)

at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:581)

at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)

at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)

at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)

at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)

at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)

at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)

at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)

at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)

at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)

at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can anyone share the Solution Please

Answer (score 0):

This will either be gmail was broken at the time (unlikely) or a firewall is blocking.